# Можно ли "правобережная" писать со строчной буквы?

Tags: прописная-строчная

отрывок из текста: "Участники мероприятия узнали интересные факты об освобождении правобережной Украины".

Answer (score 3):

ПРАВИЛЬНО: "Участники мероприятия узнали интересные факты об освобождении Правобережной Украины".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Правобере́жная Украи́на (укр. Правобере́жна Украї́на) — это имя собственное, историческое наименование территории на правом берегу по течению Днепра, в 1660—1917 годах (материал из Википедии).

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Правобережная_Украина

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Название исторической области следует отличать от выражения "правобережная часть Украины", которое может использоваться в географических описаниях, например:
"В Украине значительные площади заняты повышенными территориями, именуемыми возвышенностями. Среди них расположенная в правобережной части Украины Волыно-Подольская возвышенность".